# Android download list of images and show images in viewpager with progress dialog

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-viewpager, android-adapter, android-progressbar

Hi i am trying to show some images in viewPager those need be download before show and also i need to show progress bar while downloading. Can any one please help me sort this out. Also i am trying to all viewpager adapter form list view adapter. is it a good practice. Below is my code

Here is my list adapter

```
public class adapter extends ArrayAdapter<FriendList> {

private Context context;
private List<FriendList> frndList;
ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
LinearLayout inHorizontalScrollView;
View view;
public adapter(Context context, int resource, List<FriendList> objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);
    this.context = context;
    this.frndList = objects;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_file, parent, false);
    FriendList friensList = frndList.get(position);
    Log.v("=====================","======111111========"+friensList);
    Friend temp = friensList.getFriend();
    Log.v("=====================","======temp========"+temp);
    //inHorizontalScrollView = (LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.inhorizontalscrollview);
    List<String> imageArra = temp.getImageData();
    Log.v("=====================","======imageArra========"+imageArra.size());

    ViewPager myPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.myfivepanelpager);
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(context);
    myPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.change(imageArra);

    return view;
}

}
```

here is my viewpager adapter

```
 public class ViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

/* Adapter activity;
 int imageArray[];
 private Context context;


 public ViewPagerAdapter( Context context, int[] imgArra) {
     imageArray = imgArra;
     //activity = act;
     context = context;
 }*/
ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

private List<String> mPaths;

private Context mContext;

public ViewPagerAdapter(Context cx) {
    mContext = cx.getApplicationContext();
}

public void change(List<String> paths) {
    mPaths = paths;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return mPaths.size();
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    ImageView iv = new ImageView(mContext);
    String path = mPaths.get(position);
    Log.v("=====================","======path====11===="+path);
    new calc_stanica().execute(path, container, iv);


    try {
        Bitmap bitmap = Glide.with(mContext).load(path).asBitmap().into(-1, -1).get();
        //Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mPaths.get(position));
        iv.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    ((ViewPager) container).addView(iv, 0);
    return iv;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    container.removeView((View) object);
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object obj) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return view == (View) obj;
}


private class calc_stanica extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, Bitmap> {
    ViewGroup container;
    ImageView iv;

    /*@Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Create a progressdialog
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(mContext);
        // Set progressdialog title
        mProgressDialog.setTitle("Download Image Tutorial");
        // Set progressdialog message
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        // Show progressdialog
        mProgressDialog.show();
    }*/

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(Object... params) {

        //ArrayList<Bitmap> result = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
        String pass = (String) params[0];
        container = (ViewGroup) params[1];
        iv = (ImageView) params[2];
        //View str = (View) params[1];
        //Context ctx = (Context) params[2];
        //Log.v("================", "===passed========" + passed);


        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        try {
            // Download Image from URL
            //InputStream input = new java.net.URL(imageURL).openStream();
            // Decode Bitmap
            bitmap = Glide.with(mContext).load(pass).asBitmap().into(-1, -1).get();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //int intArray[] = new int[bitmap.getWidth()*bitmap.getHeight()];
        //result.add(bitmap);


        //Log.v("================", "===result========" + result);
        //Some calculations...

        return bitmap; //return result
    }

    //*protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... URL) {

   /* String imageURL = URL[0];

    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    ArrayList<Bitmap> list;

    try {
        // Download Image from URL
        //InputStream input = new java.net.URL(imageURL).openStream();
        // Decode Bitmap
        bitmap =  Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(imageURL).asBitmap().into(-1, -1).get();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return bitmap;*/

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {

        if(result  != null) {
            iv.setImageBitmap(result);
            ((ViewPager)container).addView(iv, 0);
        }

        //mProgressDialog.dismiss();
    }

}
```

}

it gives me error in get count and not allow to add progress bar in adapter.

Comment: please attach the logcat report(stacktrace), so that it will help to debug the issue

Comment: Hi, there is nothing in the logcat, the thing is it works but does not show any images :(

Answer (score 0):

Change your code order from

```
myPager.setAdapter(adapter);
adapter.change(imageArra);
```

to

```
adapter.change(imageArra);
myPager.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Because when you set adapter, adapter's `getCount` will be called while you only assign the list after that.
**Update**
Here is some more notes that I think you should check:

1. make sure that `imageArra` is not empty and images `path` is correct.
2. You should add a fixed height for `myfivepanelpager`.
3. Don't store `mContext` in `ViewPagerAdapter`, you don't need that.
4. In `instantiateItem`: `ImageView iv = new ImageView(mContext);` don't use application Context, use `container.getContext()`
5. You don't need this `new calc_stanica().execute(path, container, iv);` because already use `Glide`
6. Change `Bitmap bitmap = Glide.with(mContext).load(path).asBitmap().into(-1, -1).get();
       //Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mPaths.get(position));
       iv.setImageBitmap(bitmap);` 
    to 
    
   `Glide.with(mContext).load(path).asBitmap().into(iv)`
   If you have issue that glide load not correct image, read [this](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/550)
7. `((ViewPager) container).addView(iv, 0);`, I'm not sure about this but I think it's should be `((ViewPager) container).addView(iv);`

Comment: Thanks a lot solution works but it shows nothing in view. can you please guide me how to show it if you want i can share my whole code :-)

Comment: @user2423768, I update the answer base on your code, please check. If it still doesn't work then I'm out of idea now.

Comment: thanks but hard luck. Any ways can you give me any idea for my query in which i have a list that i need to show as normal listview and this list items contains list  of images those i have to show horizontally. I tried with many ways but hard luck. many thanks for you valuable time and solutions :)

Comment: @user2423768, you can use recylerview with LinearLayoutManager.Vertival for list and recylerview with LinearLayoutManager.Horizontal for items.

Comment: show a dummy image and see if its visible or not if its not then probably there is a problem in your xml may be your viewpager in not visible or its going out of window .

Comment: I have fixed the issue by setting a fixed height and width of page viewer tag. :-)